# Show duration of event Apple Calendar

Tags: calendar, ical

Is it possible to show duration of each event in Apple Calendar?

Example:

I inserted this text written in red. But I'm looking for a functionality where you can see the duration of the event.

[image]

Comment: What is iCal? Specific version of that app (that doesn’t ship anymore) or a web page or are you using iCloud calendars in google web app? If you don’t get the answer you want - consider editing to show by uploading an image and explaining a bit in words what your setup looks like. It’s hard to know if you’re on a PC or an iPhone or Apple Watch or Mac or something else.

Comment: Hi @bmike thanks for comment. See my added picture. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  When you create (or Edit) an event, you can click on the Start time, enter it, and then click on the End time, and enter that as well.  You can also make the event  All-Day.  These options are in the same window used to create the event.

To start the process, just double-click or right-click on the day of the event.  Your options will immediately be apparent.  You Title/Name the event,, enter the location now, later, or never.  If the window closes before you finish, double-click the event to edit for the times, notes etc.  Right-click will get you the same options.  Get Info on the event will also work for editing.